# Illustrator CS6 Joining anchor points

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, anchor-point

I am having problems joining both lines together that I created through cutting a circle. No matter how I moved it, it doesn't exactly line up. When I view it in outline, it doesn't line up as well. I tried removing all the snap to point and snap to grid functions but it still doesn't work. Anyone know what the problem is? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You probably didn't align them correctly, turn on Smart guides **Ctrl+U** - it'll help you to align the second circle

Comment: Turn off **Align to Pixel Grid**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select both paths and from the **Transform Window**, uncheck **Align to pixel Grid**:

[image: Align]

Next time, when you create an **Illustrator** file, make sure to uncheck **Align New Objects to Pixel Grid**

[image: new]